# IOS unable to pass the result set from the ViewCOntroller to another one

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, protocols

I would like to implement the module for passing the data bundle from SliderViewController to another one. When it comes to the execution , it shows the following console message:

I have no clue on what is going on for successfully passing the data , even which line of the code causing this issue

```
Break on objc_exception_throw to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
2014-06-25 17:01:20.471 marker[3008:60b] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSIBPrototypingLayoutConstraint:0x185bc390 'IB auto generated at build time for view with fixed frame' V:|-(175)-[UISlider:0x185b6b90]   (Names: '|':UIView:0x185b7960 )>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x18345f00 h=--& v=--& UISlider:0x185b6b90.midY == + 190>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x185af410 h=--& v=--& V:[UISlider:0x185b6b90(176)]>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSIBPrototypingLayoutConstraint:0x185bc390 'IB auto generated at build time for view with fixed frame' V:|-(175)-[UISlider:0x185b6b90]   (Names: '|':UIView:0x185b7960 )>

Break on objc_exception_throw to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
```

The below is my work:

Original ViewController:

```
#pragma mark - Protocol Methods

-(void)setVerticalName:(float)firstName {

    _verticalSliderValue = firstName;
}

-(void)setCircleName:(float)lastName {

    _circleSliderValue = lastName;
}




-(void) mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView didLongPressAtCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coordinate{

    sliderVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SliderViewController"];
    sliderVC.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.0 alpha:0.1];
    self.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCurrentContext;
    [self presentViewController:sliderVC animated:YES completion:NULL];

    [sliderVC setDelegate:self];

    if(_verticalSliderValue!=0 && _circleSliderValue!=0){
        CheckPoints *myCar=[[CheckPoints alloc] init];
        [myCar setState:0];
        [myCar setLatitude:coordinate.latitude];
        [myCar setLongitude:coordinate.longitude];
        NSString* theTextValue = @"Desitnation";
        [myCar setDesp:theTextValue];

        [array addObject:myCar];
        CheckPoints *lastChk = array.lastObject;
        [self writeToTextFile:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@%@%@%@", lastChk.getDesp , @"\n",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", lastChk.getLatitude],
                               @"\n", [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", lastChk.getLongitude], @"\n" ]];
        NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        [defaults setFloat:lastChk.getLatitude forKey:@"lati"];
        [defaults setFloat:lastChk.getLongitude forKey:@"longi"];
        [defaults setObject:lastChk.getDesp forKey:@"desp"];
        [defaults synchronize];

        for (int i = 0; i < [array count]; i++) {
            CheckPoints *current =  [array objectAtIndex:i];
            if(current.getLatitude != lastChk.getLatitude && current.getLongitude != lastChk.getLongitude){
                [current setState:1];
                NSString* previousTitle = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", @"Checkpoint" ,[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", i+1]];
                [current setDesp:previousTitle];
            }
        }
        [self addMarkers];
    }
```

SliderViewCOntroller.h

```
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "EFCircularSlider.h"

@protocol passValues <NSObject>

-(void)setVerticalName:(float)firstName;
-(void)setCircleName:(float)lastName;

@end


@interface SliderViewController : UIViewController
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *uiValue;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISlider *uiSlider;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *btnReset;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *uiValue2;
@property (strong, nonatomic)  EFCircularSlider* circularSlider;
@property (nonatomic) float verticalSliderValue;
@property (nonatomic) float circleSliderValue;
@property (retain)id <passValues> delegate;


- (IBAction)reset:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)sliderChange:(id)sender;


@end
```

SliderViewController.m:

```
- (IBAction)reset:(id)sender {
    [self writeToTextFile:valueV :valueC];
    self.uiValue.text =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f" , 0.00];
    [self.uiSlider setValue:0.00];
    self.uiValue2.text =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f" , 0.00];
    [_circularSlider setCurrentValue:0.0f];
  //  UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main_iPhone" bundle:nil];
   // ViewController *fc = (ViewController*)[UIStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"FormView"];


    [[self delegate]setVerticalName:_verticalSliderValue];

    [[self delegate]setCircleName:_circleSliderValue];

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

  }
```

Comment: you log indicates there are auto layout problems, which has nothing to do with passing data.

Comment: Do you mean that I have to call addMarkers at method  viewWillAppear ?

Comment: No. It means your auto layout has too many constraints. You should learn how to use auto layout or just don't use it. I prefer the latter.

Comment: I don't understand. I just imitate the onActivityResult @ Android to pass the values among the ViewControllers. Never linked to auto layouts with respect to my working

Comment: wait....what Android? aren't you working on iOS project?

Comment: I want to make ios working as android as i can pass the pass the value from A viewCOntroller to another B ViewController in the way that after initiating A from B, I set the values at A , finish ViewController A and hence going back to B with result from A got

Comment: you should learn iOS programming first. [The Big Nerd Ranch](http://www.amazon.com/iOS-Programming-Ranch-Edition-Guides-ebook/dp/B00IG8TGZ8/ref=zg_bs_6133980011_1) is pretty good.